# how to check given Url is "Youtube " "Vimeo" and "Unknow " video URL with the help regular expression . in objective c IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9

i have list of url watch hard coded  in my app. some of URL is belong to youtube some are belong to vimeo are some are unknown video URL . so i want play video in its  respective environment .

Comment: Have a look into oEmbed at http://oembed.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you have only 3 options you may check for rangeofString in the string/url like this:

```
NSString *string = url.absoluteString;
if ([string rangeOfString:@"youtube" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"Youtube link found");
} else if ([string rangeOfString:@"vimeo" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"Vimeo link found");
} else {
        NSLog(@"Unknown link found");
}
```

Comment: Yeah and first run it through NSURLComponents to make sure you match against domain name, not the entire URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using swift 5.2 then it will be helpful

```
let string = url.absoluteString
if (string as NSString).range(of: "youtube", options: .caseInsensitive).location != NSNotFound {
    print("Youtube link found")
} else if (string as NSString).range(of: "vimeo", options: .caseInsensitive).location != NSNotFound {
    print("Vimeo link found")
} else {
    print("Unknown link found")
}
```